# On Airflow, getting Connection refused while connecting to SMTP host

Tags: python, smtp, airflow, smtplib

Following something similar as explained in below article for sending emails via SMTP server in Airflow:
https://towardsdatascience.com/automating-emails-in-apache-airflow-a-how-to-guide-1d2330a29d1e

I didn't use default airflow.cfg to configure for smtp host as in our production env, we don't have control over it.
But in prod, seems Airflow is not able to connect to the SMTP host, while I could run the same code in local and get the emails.
Error as below:

[Error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KeDb.png)

We also checked via a standalone python script on prod server, that we're able to reach to SMTP host, so it's not really issue with the host but Airflow.

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 3):

Well, we found it’s the issue connecting from production boxes to the remote SMTP server, probably due to a firewall between client and server.
We confirmed it via running a python script in those prod boxes and it’s failing at below line while connecting:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server) 

server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message.as_string())
```

Error:
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Apologies for confusion before.

Earlier we tried via sendmail unix command and it worked and so the confusion:

```
sendmail email_address -s smtp_server

Subject: Test mail from prod_env

Hello, email received
```

So it’s not issue with Airflow, but just connecting from prod servers to smtp server.
Thanks.